# Site Counter Image - How to fit the Numbers into it

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

[image]

I have the above image that I will use as a site counter. I need to now get white numbers to sit on top of this that I can increment with Jquery.

I can easily put a number on top of this and increment it with JQUERY but I just not sure how to get the number to be spaced out correctly. eg: the first 3 digits distance is different to the forth.

Does anyone have advice on how to get a number - say 1 Million (1000000) to site behind this and so it can be increment by JQUERY?

thankyou

Comment: Does it have to be that image? which way are you counting and what are you counting? plenty of jquery plugins out there that do what you ask with nice UI aswell, for example http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/11/jquery-countdown-scripts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values in a html unorderd list and apply appropriate  css  properties to get the values above the image. After that with jquery increment margin-right of 3rd and 6th li element to get align the elemnts correctly. Use jquery nth child property to alter the style:

```
    $('ul li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('extra-margin-class')
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gVVAV/4/

> Updated the demo with your image.

Comment: looks great... how would I then increment the number - like say I wanted to add 20 to the total number but I want it to increment one number at a time - thus count up 20 digits one at a time...

Comment: not sure why but the HTML doesn't seem to appear now... hummmm

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each of your number to `<span>` and give `float:right`:

```
span
{
    padding-left: 3px;
    float: right;
}
```

and finally jQuery:

```
$('span').each(function(index){
    if((index+1) % 3 == 0 && index != 0) 
        $(this).css('padding-left', '20px');
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5M7n6/3/)

Remember: you have to pass your number other way around.